# Problems with salesforce summer'13 Release immediate="true"

Tags: salesforce-id, actionfunction, api-28

I have written code snippet in Visualforce in using actionFunction with immediate="true", so that validations bypasses the page. but due to upgradation  to summer'13 the immediate="true" doesn't work now. it does not allows to  by pass the validation during actionFunction call. Is it a salesforce bug or i am doing something wrong.

try this code in both spring'13 and summer'13

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="test1">
        <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.BirthDate}" required="true"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" immediate="true" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please try the below code in summer'13 as well as spring'13. Select the values from picklist and observe the changes. also select 'Other' from picklist.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pagemessages id="error"></apex:pagemessages>

<apex:actionFunction name="dynamic" action="{!save}" rerender="content" immediate="true">
    <apex:param value="" name="p1" assignTo="{!Contact.LeadSource}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>


<apex:outputPanel id="content" >
<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
     <apex:outputLabel value="Selected lead Source: {!Contact.LeadSource}" />
     <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.Department}" required="true" />
     <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.BirthDate}" required="true" rendered="{!(Contact.LeadSource == 'Other')}" />
     <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Source: "></apex:outputLabel>        
       <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.LeadSource}" onChange="dynamic(this.value);" />        
     </apex:pageblockSectionItem> 

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:outputPanel>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you post your code.

Comment: @PJC i have added the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Salesforce has resolved this issue. Thanks SFDC !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save a contact through the standardcontrollers save action, without validating the contact.name (which is a readonly field on contact by the way, you wouldn't be able to set that anyway)

This is your code in a page:
[image]

Your commandbutton will ignore the validation on the **page** but will still fail on validation rules, possible trigger.addErrors and/or **required fields on object level**, in your case the field Contact.LastName still is required, and your save will fail.

[Order Of Execution](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Comment: ok change it to birthdate. then what happens

Comment: that doesn't matter, did you read the last part of my answer, you still have requirements (on object level) which cause your save to fail. This can also happen because of Validation rules and/or .addErrors in apex in a trigger for example.

You aren't using immediate="true" correctly

Comment: I tested this on a production org (which is still Spring) and a sandbox (which is summer) both won't work

Comment: Please just do a favour to me, try the code i have recently posted. this will surely clarifies you the behaviour change in summer'13 and spring'13. Please try it once.

Comment: There does seem to be a difference in summer / spring, I suggest logging a case with salesforce.

Comment: I can attest I am also encountering this bug in summer 13.